# What is the "Current message level"?

Tags: linux, network-interface

What is the "Current message level" of an interface that `ethtool` provides? E.g.

`ethtool eth1
    [Other stuff]
    Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)`

What is the message level? What is message level 20?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the level of 'debugging messages/data' from the driver.

It is not quite standardized. Some more documentation is available in [`Documentation/networking/netif-msg.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netif-msg.txt) in your kernel source folder.

You may be able to use ethtool to set the message level

```
ethtool -s eth1 msglvl [level]
```

Note that the levels may vary by driver and you should look these up for your specific driver. The mask in a hex (0x... form) or decimal input should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks! And to edit the message level use `ethtool -s eth1 msglvl [level]`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-ethtool.html